# Javascript xmlhttprequest docx file context from google drive

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I tried to get the file content of docx file following the steps in the following link:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

The problem I have is the return data seems corrupted, something like the following:

```
��▬h��↕E6M��~��3�3∟�9�� � �►��/2�:���♂�4��]�♀I�R���►
$SB6Q���c↔��H�=;+
���►q�3Tdכ��@!T��hEl_�|�I�↨��h(�^:▬�[h̓D♠��f���♠*���ݾ��M→
�1⌂♦"N�↑�o�]�7U$��A6����♠�W��k`�f▬♫��K�Z�^‼�0{<Z�▼�]F�����

                             ���J♥A♀��♣�a�}7�
"���H�w"�♥���☺w♫̤ھ�� �P�^����O֛���;�<♠�aYՠ؛`G�kxm��PY�[��g
Gΰino�/<���<�1��ⳆA$>"f3��\�ȾT��∟I S�������W♥����Y
```

Any tips would be he

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: data looks fine to me